Can you pull a pulk on deep snow?
how is it pulling a pulk over deep snow?
must poles be used or a rope is enough?
I understand it has many depends, so please elaborate.

You mean a modern form of something like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Engag%C3%A9_mit_einem_indianischen_Hundeschlitten_by_Maximilian_zu_Wied-Neuwied.jpg ?

Usually a very short question that demands a very long answer is not a good match for this family of sites. It would be best if you think more about and describe the specifics of an actual situation and how you've already tried to solve it.

Can you pull a pulk//sled over deep snow? Yes.
Can you do it casually in all situations without consideration of the exact terrain and your team layout? Definitely not.
Should you evaluate exactly what route you would take and tools you would need accordingly right down to the times of day for travel, so you can evaluate if a pulk is possible or best, and how to pull it? Absolutely.
It is impossible to tell you if//how a pulk could be pulled without a specific scenario beyond that. It would be a case by case basis. Not all deep snow is equal, not all pulks are equal, etc etc etc.
That said a pulk in deep snow sounds like something in a write up abstract about something that went unplanned-- certainly not sounding like an ideal intentional choice. At least on anything but flat//near flat ground with snow shoes. You can look up videos of troops and rangers tieing up sleds//pulks in snow terrain for basic examples if you'd like :)
The biggest danger of deep snow is how much work you have to put into moving through it, leading to exhaustion, excessive sweating, and balance mistakes.  A pulk probably isn't gonna be helping with any of those things. Also if you are in anyway near avalanche territory a pulk sounds very counter-helpful to treading on the areas least likely to avalanche.
